# Pronoun for “la polico”

Tags: pronouns

If I understand correctly, in English, “the police” is effectively plural and therefore you end up conjugating verbs in the plural and also refer to it using a plural pronoun. For example:

> The police **are** dangerous
>
> The police **are** coming and **they are** dangerous because **they** have weapons

However, in other languages such as French, a similar word would be singular. For example:

> La police **est dangeureuse**.
>
> La police **arrive** et **elle est dangeureuse** parce qu’**elle a** des armes.

The pronoun used in French is singular and I think it effectively works like the pronoun *it*.

In Esperanto, *la polico* is quite clearly singular because it doesn’t end in *j*. That makes me think we should also decline the adjectives  in the singular.

However, I’m not sure which pronoun makes the most sense. The police are several people being referred to in the singular. This makes me think that logically any of *li*, *ŝi*, *ri*, *ĝi* or *ili* might be debatable. However I would instinctively use *ili* like so:

> La polico estas **danĝera**.
>
> La polico alvenas kaj **ili** estas **danĝeraj** ĉar **ili** havas armilojn.

This also ends up with the slightly odd situation that when the police is referred to by a noun the adjective is *danĝera* whereas when it is referred to by a pronoun it is *danĝeraj*.

Is this correct or I am being incorrectly influenced by English?

Comment: I think in English, too, this may depend on whether you conceptualize "the police" primarily as an institution (which may be represented by a group of its members, especially when it *comes* to a place) or rather primarily as a group of people, that simply act as an institution. In the former case, I'd use "it" and in the latter "they". And while I'm not a native speaker of English, I have the feeling that the former case may be more common than the latter in at least formal English. (For colloquial English, I'm not so sure.)

Comment: Might also be different between different English-speaking communities, regions or countries, I could imagine.

Comment: `La policistoj` (ili) or `la policteamo` (ĝi). Because of that `armiloj` _policistoj_ was meant. An anonymous `ili` could make sense; but better change `la polico`.